# REST resource with multiple views

Tags: rest

We are trying to follow a quite strict idiom for our REST service however we have come across a situation where we have two clients who require different representations of the same resource.  One is front-end and they would prefer a very minimal resource with only the fields they require and in a more flattened structure (for performance), the other requires all fields that we have in our data store in a heavily nested structure.  What is the idiomatic way for REST services to deal with this given the canonical URL should be the same as they are accessing the same resource.  We thought of adding projections to the request but with this the structure would still be quite nested which causes performance issues in the JS client as it will have to walk through the structure and flatten it, something that can be quite costly when the number of resources returned is high.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest there are two alternatives:

1) If the query field can vary, you could specify the fields (structure) you want as query parameters. This is common in REST APIs. With no specification, you would return a default list of fields. What should be default or not depends on the service, but in general the minimal set makes a better default for performance. In order to avoid listing all fields, something like `fields=all` could be used. In your case `structure` might make more sense.

2) You can encode the field request in a custom request headers. Some would argue that this is the more REST-ful approach as you're only modifying the format of the response and not the underlying action invoked, and therefore the URL should be the same.

In practice, most services prefer the first approach as it's considered more approachable.

Personally, I think it's a marginal choice. I prefer to encode the return media (JSON, HTML, XML, etc.) in the `Accept` header. Any decent developer has tools that make it easy enough to set the headers, but the `fields` query parameter idiom is, in my experience, far more prevalent and there's a great deal to be said for convention.

Note, if you use the headers approach, you should probably not use the `Accept` header for the structure/field specification. Add your own header if you go that route.

Comment: Cool, I hadn't thought of headers.